# How to create multiple excel files in for loop using phpexcel library

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am using php excel library to create multiple excel files in one click. I am using for loop on the the header functions. but it does not work. any body please help me.

Thank YOU

Comment: Any chance you want to show what you have done so far, otherwise folks really can't help too much.

Comment: Could you tell us exactly what wrong it is?

Comment: you want to return to download user all the files ? you can do this by save the files on the server and return the links

Comment: $objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();
for($i=0; $i <2; $i++) {
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('A1', 'Something');
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Name of Sheet 1');
$objPHPExcel->createSheet();

header("Content-Type: application/excel");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".ucwords('test')."-Data-".$i.".xls");


header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");    


}

Comment: You can't download multiple files (even of the same type) to a browser in one go unless you zip them all up into one package and download that package

Comment: well thanks all of you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTTP doesn't support multiple files in a single download. You can only transfer one file from server side at a time.

1.Zip/Tar the multiple files on the server and transfer that zip, there's no way to download more than one file per request.

1. Save the files on the server and return the download links in HTML page.
2. Use JavaScript to window.open multiple files for download.